About a birational automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^2$
Define $F(x,y)$ to be the triangle center X(1138) of the triangle $\{(0,0),(1,0),(x,y)\}$.
$$
F(x,y)=\left(\tiny\begin{aligned}
    \frac{(12 x - 21 x^2 + 6 x^3 + 3 x^4 - 5 y^2 - 2 x y^2 + 6 x^2 y^2 + 3 y^4) (9 x^3 - 18 x^4 + 9 x^5 + 9 x y^2 - 30 x^2 y^2 + 18 x^3 y^2 - 4 y^4 + 9 x y^4)}{3 ((y-2 x y)^2+(3 x^2-3 x+y^2)^2)^2},\\
    \frac{(-9 x^2 + 27 x^3 - 27 x^4 + 9 x^5 + 3 y^2 + 3 x y^2 - 24 x^2 y^2 + 18 x^3 y^2 - 5 y^4 + 9 x y^4) (9 x^3 - 18 x^4 + 9 x^5 + 9 x y^2 - 30 x^2 y^2 + 18 x^3 y^2 - 4 y^4 + 9 x y^4)}{3 y ((y-2 x y)^2+(3 x^2-3 x+y^2)^2)^2}
\end{aligned}\right)
$$
$F$ is an involution ($F$ interchanges pairs of points) $F\circ F=\text{id}$, by this thread.
$F$ has four singularities: $(0,0),(1,0),(\frac12,\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2)$.
The question is to find the curves $S$ such that $F(S)\subseteq S$.

Example 1
If $(x,y)$ is on the line $x=\frac12$, then $F(x,y)$ stays on the line $x=\frac12$ by symmetry.
So the line $x=\frac12$ satisfies the condition.
Moreover, if $S$ satisfies the condition then so does the reflection of $S$ across $x=\frac12$.

Example 2
$F$ has infinitely many fixed points.
Simplifying
$F(x,y)=(x,y)$ we get a curve
$$3 y^6-\left(3 x^2-3 x+5\right) y^4-3 (x-1) x \left(5 x^2-5 x+3\right) y^2-9 (x-1)^3 x^3=0$$
through the four singularities of $F$.

Example 3
$F(x,\sqrt3x)=(1+x,\sqrt3x)$, so the pair of parallel lines joining the four singularities of $F$
$$(y-\sqrt3x)(y-\sqrt3(x-1))=0\label1\tag1$$satisfies the condition.
Reflecting across $x=\frac12$, we get the other pair of parallel lines joining the four singularities of $F$
$$(y+\sqrt3x)(y+\sqrt3(x-1))=0\label2\tag2$$
also satisfies the condition.

To generalize Example 3, consider the pencil of conics through four singularities of $F$
$${\cal C}:\quad\eqref{1}-\mu\eqref{2}$$
for a constant $\mu\in\mathbb{P}^1$.
The center of $\cal C$ is $(\frac12,0)$.

(I) The point $F(x,y)\in\cal C$ for all point $(x,y)\in\cal C$.
(II) The slope of the line through $(x,y)$ and $F(x,y)$ is the same for all points $(x,y)\in\cal C$.

So the restriction of $F$ to $\cal C$ is a projective transformation.
(III) $\cal C$ is the locus of the point $P$ such that the Euler line of the triangle $\{(0,0),(1,0),P\}$ is parallel to the Euler line of the triangle $\{(0,0),(1,0),(x,y)\}$.
In particular, the intersection of the line through $(x,y)$ parallel to the Euler line of the triangle $\{(0,0),(1,0),(x,y)\}$ and the circumcircle lies on $\cal C$.


To prove (I) is equivalent to prove that $$\mu(x,y)=\mu(F(x,y))\tag3\label3$$
where $
\mu(x,y)=\frac{(y-\sqrt3x)(y-\sqrt3(x-1))}{(y+\sqrt3x)(y+\sqrt3(x-1))}
$ is the constant that determines $\cal C$.
Plugging the long expression of $F(x,y)$ into \eqref{3} proves (I).
How do you prove (II) and (III)? I tried hard, but I was lost in the computation.

The above are examples of curves $S$ such that $F(S)\subseteq S$
Are there any other $S$?

There is a large amount of ambiguity in the setup of the question. Is $F$ defined by specific polynomials, or is $F$ simply any polynomial involution of the plane satisfying one or more of the latter sentences? By plane transformation do you mean linear? Affine? Birational? Polynomal? Even if this is implicit from your tags this would be useful to readers in yhe future

Ok. The question is still very hard to read as written. I suggest rephrasing with the definition of the function at the start.

@Mummytheturkey Ok. I have rephrased with the definition of the function at the start.
